# How to detect or prove the recurrence relations is periodic sequences using Z3?

Tags: recursion, z3, z3py

How to detect or prove that this recurrence relation defines a periodic sequence.

Here is an example A>0 is fixed

[image]

where A,x are natural numbers and the function f return a natural value.

Can you suggest any method to detect this type of recurrence relation is periodic sequences? I have tried following SMT(Z3) program to detect such recurrence (please correct me if I am wrong)

```
s=Solver()
s.add(A>0)
s.add(ForAll([n],Implies(n>=0,y4(n1 + 1) == If(y4(n)<=A,y4(n) + 1,y4(n)-1))))
s.add(y4(0) == 0)
s.add(Not(ForAll([n],Exists([k],Implies(And(k>0,n>=0),y4(n)==y4(n+k))))))
```

The query return `"unsat"`. But what I found that for following query Z3 return same result `"unsat"`.

```
s=Solver()
s.add(A>0)
s.add(ForAll([n],Implies(n>=0,y4(n1 + 1) == If(y4(n)<=A,y4(n) + 1,y4(n)+2))))
s.add(y4(0) == 0)
s.add(Not(ForAll([n],Exists([k],Implies(And(k>0,n>=0),y4(n)==y4(n+k))))))
```

Can you please point out what is wrong in my query? And what is the other possible way how to detect or prove the recurrence relations are periodic sequences?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
(declare-fun f (Int Int) Int)

(assert (forall ((a Int)) (= (f 0 a) 0)))
(assert (forall ((x Int) (a Int)) (=> (and (>= x 0) (>= a 0) (> (f x a) a)) (= (f (+ x 1) a) (- (f x a) 1)))))
(assert (forall ((x Int) (a Int)) (=> (and (>= x 0) (>= a 0) (<= (f x a) a)) (= (f (+ x 1) a) (+ (f x a) 1)))))
(assert (forall ((x Int) (y Int) (a Int)) (=> (and (>= x 0) (> y x) (>= a 0)) (not (= (f x a) (f y a))))))
(check-sat)
```

although it doesn't say that f is periodic.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. Can you help me to understand 
s=Solver()
s.add(A>0)
s.add(ForAll([n],Implies(n>=0,y4(n1 + 1) == If(y4(n)<=A,y4(n) + 1,y4(n)+2))))
s.add(y4(0) == 0)
s.add(Not(ForAll([n],Exists([k],Implies(And(k>0,n>=0),y4(n)==y4(n+k))))))        why it return unsat

Answer (score 1):

Please always include the full code in your samples; as what you have given isn't valid code for people to run and observe.

Assuming your code is actually the following:

```
from z3 import *
s=Solver()
A=Int('A')
n=Int('n')
k=Int('k')
y4 = Function('f', IntSort(), IntSort())
s.add(A>0)
s.add(ForAll([n],Implies(n>=0,y4(n + 1) == If(y4(n)<=A,y4(n) + 1,y4(n)-1))))
s.add(y4(0) == 0)
s.add(Not(ForAll([n],Exists([k],Implies(And(k>0,n>=0),y4(n)==y4(n+k))))))
```

You can see what Z3 is producing by adding:

```
print s.sexpr()
print s.check()
```

If you run this script, you get:

```
(declare-fun A () Int)
(declare-fun f (Int) Int)
(assert (> A 0))
(assert (forall ((n Int))
  (let ((a!1 (= (f (+ n 1)) (ite (<= (f n) A) (+ (f n) 1) (- (f n) 1)))))
    (=> (>= n 0) a!1))))
(assert (= (f 0) 0))
(assert (let ((a!1 (forall ((n Int))
             (exists ((k Int))
               (=> (and (> k 0) (>= n 0)) (= (f n) (f (+ n k))))))))
  (not a!1)))

unsat
```

And you can see the issue; your last assertion says there exists an `n`, such that for all `k` periodicity *does not* hold. (Since you put a `Not` wrapper.) Clearly, that is `unsat`.

In somewhat more idiomatic Z3, I'd code your problem as follows:

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver ()

A = Int ('A')
s.add(A > 0)

f = Function('f', IntSort(), IntSort())
x = Int ('x')

s.add(f(0) == 0)
s.add(ForAll(x, Implies(x >= 0, f(x + 1) == If(A >= f(x), f(x)+1, f(x)-1))))

k = Int('k')
s.add(ForAll(x, Exists(k, f(x+k) == f(x))))

print s.sexpr()
print s.check()
```

But expecting Z3 to prove this would be naive. Indeed, when I run it, I get:

```
(declare-fun A () Int)
(declare-fun f (Int) Int)
(assert (> A 0))
(assert (= (f 0) 0))
(assert (forall ((x Int))
  (let ((a!1 (= (f (+ x 1)) (ite (>= A (f x)) (+ (f x) 1) (- (f x) 1)))))
    (=> (>= x 0) a!1))))
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (exists ((k Int)) (= (f (+ x k)) (f x)))))

 [Ctrl-C]
```

The modeling looks correct to me in this case, but Z3 fails to answer, so I had to Ctrl-C stop it after a while.

But the good thing is you can take that SMTLib and put it in a file, attach a `(check-sat)` at the end, and run Z3 as follows:

```
z3 -v:10 a.smt2 a.smt2
```

And it'll print you a lot of steps on what it's doing. My guess is that it's lost in the quantifier instantiation process. The typical solution is to provide quantifier patterns, but it's not clear to me what they would be in this case. There are some examples here 
http://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/advanced-examples.htm that might be of assistance though.